# Prove that the sequence $a_n = n(-1)^n$ is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let's prove that:

1. Sequence has no upper bound
2. Sequence has no lower bound

Restating 1. and 2. we get

1. $\nexists c \in \mathbb R$ such that $a_n \leq c \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N$
2. $\nexists d \in \mathbb R$ such that $d \leq a_n \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N$

*Proof.* *[by contradiction]*

1. Let's assume the opposite of 1. — sequence has an upper bound : $\exists c \in \mathbb R$ such that $a_n \leq c \space \forall n \in \mathbb N$, that is $n(-1)^n \leq c$.

Then set $n=|\lceil c \rceil| \cdot 2$. With $n$ chosen this way, $n \in \mathbb N$ and $n$ is an even number.

We get $|\lceil c \rceil| \cdot 2 \cdot (-1)^{|\lceil c \rceil| \cdot 2} = |\lceil c \rceil| \cdot 2 \leq c$. Which is not true — we arrived at a contradiction, hence there is no upper bound.

2. Assume opposite of 2. — the sequence has a lower bound: $\exists d \in \mathbb R$ such that $d \leq a_n \space \forall n \in \mathbb N$, that is $d \leq n(-1)^n$.

Then set $n = |\lfloor d \rfloor \cdot 2 + 1|$. With $n$ chosen this way $n \in \mathbb N$ and $n$ is an odd number.

We get $d \leq |\lfloor d \rfloor \cdot 2 + 1| \cdot (-1)^{|\lfloor d \rfloor \cdot 2 + 1|} = - |\lfloor d \rfloor \cdot 2 + 1| \leq -2 |\lfloor d \rfloor| - 1 \leq |\lfloor d \rfloor|$ which holds if $0 < d$ but since our sequence obviously has members $a_n < 0$, let's assume that $d < 0$ (*). With this in mind, $d < |\lfloor d \rfloor|$ is a contradiction, hence there is no lower bound.

This completes the proof.

* I wasn't sure about this part, but I couldn't see a way out without assuming $d<0$.

Comment: It's completely fine to say $a_1 = -1$, so $d \leq -1$ and then use that later on. But apart from that your arithmetic with negative numbers and absolute values is wrong. If you fix that you should end up not even needing to make the assumption that $d < 0$.

Comment: @SuhailSherif ah I see, thanks for pointing it out. I could say $d \leq -2| \lfloor d \rfloor |$ and then it doesn't matter if $d$ is less or greater than zero, it's false nevertheless.  does this fix it?

Comment: That would simplify things, but the line before that isn't true when d is negative. Might I suggest using $\lceil |d| \rceil \cdot 2 + 1$ instead? This gets you a large absolute value and an odd value.

Comment: @SuhailSherif hm, I don't see how that makes it different, since $| \lfloor d \rfloor \cdot 2 + 1| \leq | \lfloor d \rfloor \cdot 2 | + |1| = | \lfloor d \rfloor | \cdot 2 + 1$, which is the same as what you said. Are you saying that how I put it won't get me an odd number or that it won't me get a natural number? sorry if I don't see some obvious problem with it and thanks for going back and forth

Comment: For most d your number is also large in absolute value and odd. The problem was that since the absolute value in your choice was outside the expression, when $\lfloor d \rfloor$ is negative the $+1$ takes away from the magnitude of the number. And so in that case the statement $- |\lfloor d \rfloor \cdot 2 + 1| \leq -2 |\lfloor d \rfloor| - 1$ is false.

Comment: @SuhailSherif I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much faster (and, in my opinion, neater) way would be to show that $|a_n| = n$ is unbounded, and then to prove that for any sequence $x_n$ the following holds:
$$x_n \text{ is bounded if and only if } |x_n| \text{ is bounded.}$$

---

**Edit:**

If you wish to prove that the sequence $a_n$ does not have an upper bound nor a lower bound (which, as far as I'm aware, is a stronger requirement than simply being unbounded), you can consider the subsequences $a_{2k} = 2k$ and $a_{2k+1} = -(2k+1)$. You can then prove the following holds for any sequence $x_n$:

$x_n$ has no upper (or lower, respectively) bound if and only if there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ which does not have an upper (or lower, respectively) bound.

Comment: How does this prove that $a_n$ has no lower bound? Not disagreeing just curious since the lack of a lower bound relies on the fact that it can be negative.

Comment: @RobertMurray Ah, by "unbounded" I understood it to mean "there is no upper bound or there is no lower bound". I will edit my answer to deal with the case of wantiny "no upper bound and no lower bound".

Comment: ^ wanting*. Sorry, careless fingers.

Comment: nice suggestions! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The step (*) is fine although you may want to word it differently as you are not really assuming but deducing. You may say that $a_1 = 1(-1)^1 = -1$ and $d < a_1$ so in particular $d < 0$.

Note that the method you use is fine but it may have been easier to mathematically state the sequence has no upper bound as $\forall c \in \mathbb R,\, \exists n \in \mathbb N \text{ such that } c < a_n$. You could similarly state the condition of having no lower bound.

Comment: ah I see, deducing indeed it was. I actually edited out stating it as you suggest because it seemed more apt stylistically to just use negation on $\exists$ since the proof proceeds with assuming the opposite statement which is the same as the original just without the negation i.e. looked simpler to me. thanks!

Comment: @powerline What I was alluding to with my suggestion of rewriting the statement was it may admit an easier proof instead of what you have. The argument would more or less look the same but it would be a direct proof rather than a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath well I resorted to contradiction since I didn’t know to prove it directly. how would be proceed with a direct proof? Perhaps induction?

Comment: @powerline Let $c \in \mathbb R$. Choose $n = 2\cdot (|\lceil c \rceil| + 1)$. Then, $a_{n} = 2\cdot (|\lceil c \rceil| + 1) \geq c + 1 > c$. Hence, the sequence $(a_{n})$ is not bounded above.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

For $a_n = n(-1)^n$ ...

Assume lower bound exists and is $l = p(-1)^p$, $p$ has to be odd.

The next odd number is $p + 2$

$(p + 2)(-1)^{p + 2}$. We see that $(p + 2) > p$ and $(-1)^{p + 2} < 0$

So $(p + 2)(-1)^{p + 2} < p(-1)^p$

Therefore, $a_n = n(-1)^n$ has no lower bound

We can construct a similar argument for the upper bound.

Comment: thanks for responding! if I'm understanding this correctly, you are saying we can prove by induction that the subsequence $a_{2k-1}$ has no lower bound. the general idea appears to me the same as what @RyanTay said, so I think it should work